# Android Gradle: Include repository information for Dependency in pom of library artifact

Tags: java, maven, android-gradle-plugin

I have two projects i'm developing.

1 is a Library which is consumed by external entities.

2 is a library which is consumed by 1.

Right now if I want a project (3) that depends on 1 I have to include the repository information for 2 in 3's build.gradle

How do I package that information (2's repository) in 1's pom so that 3 doesn't have to include that information?

The pom for 1 doesn't include the repository information for its dependencies by default and I'm not sure how to add that into the pom.